# How Can I get the data from two collections from firebase in flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm making an app of mechanics and users, here: I calling the collections from 'mecanicos' collection, but I'm how to call the two collections? I mean the users and mecanicos collection

Here is te chode:

```
  Future getDataFromFirestore() async {
await _firebaseFirestore
    .collection("mecanicos")
    .doc(_firebaseAuth.currentUser!.uid)
    .get()
    .then((DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
  _userModel = UserModel(
    name: snapshot['name'],
    cedula: snapshot['cedula'],
    local: snapshot['local'],
    email: snapshot['email'],
    bio: snapshot['bio'],
    profilePic: snapshot['profilePic'],
    createdAt: snapshot['createdAt'],
    phoneNumber: snapshot['phoneNumber'],
    uid: snapshot['uid'],
  );
  _uid = userModel.uid;
});
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the references of your documents in two separate variables and then use Future.wait to wait for both responses. Once you have received the responses, you can use both "mecanicos" and "user" snapshots to further process the data. Hope this helps.

Code:

```
Future getDataFromFirestore() async {
  final mecanicosReference = _firebaseFirestore
      .collection("mecanicos")
      .doc(_firebaseAuth.currentUser!.uid);
  final userReference = _firebaseFirestore
      .collection("users")
      .doc(_firebaseAuth.currentUser!.uid);

  final responses = await Future.wait([mecanicosReference.get(), userReference.get()])
  
  final mecanicosSnapshot = responses[0];
  final userResponse = responses[1];

  _userModel = UserModel(
      name: mecanicosSnapshot['name'],
      cedula: mecanicosSnapshot['cedula'],
      local: mecanicosSnapshot['local'],
      email: mecanicosSnapshot['email'],
      bio: mecanicosSnapshot['bio'],
      profilePic: mecanicosSnapshot['profilePic'],
      createdAt: mecanicosSnapshot['createdAt'],
      phoneNumber: mecanicosSnapshot['phoneNumber'],
      uid: mecanicosSnapshot['uid'],
    );
    _uid = userModel.uid;
}
```